# What is a 'rocker slab'?

Tags: civil-engineering, reinforced-concrete

See below for an extract from a general arrangement drawing from the 1980s. It makes reference to a '9" rocker slab' which appears to be a slab supported by steel beams.

[image]

Does anyone have any more information on the construction details of a rocker slab?

Comment: I guess the word "Rocker" is a descriptive term here, that to indicate this is a system of concrete panes simply laying on the edge beams without composite action.

Comment: drawing is from the US, right?

Comment: @mart it is British

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this [reference](https://www.academia.edu/9773741/CONTAINER_TERMINAL_AND_INTERMODAL_RAIL_YARD_OPERATIONAL_AREA_CONSIDERATION_FOR_PAVEMENT_DESIGN) , a white paper from a firm "Moffatand Nichol," which says

> Localized areas found between structure and external service yard can
> be designed as a form of articulation or ‘rocker’ slab, which as the
> name suggests, allows for normal movements irrespective of on-going
> settlements. While rocker slabs may be a solution for particular
> applications, they can never provide an operationally friendly
> solution for large storage areas or service yards.

My take, skimming some other sites' documents which mention but don't strictly define them, is that  a "rocker slab" is a single-cast piece of concrete which rests on supports at both ends (and possibly the sides), thus joining two separate parts of framing. Quite possibly without being bonded in place (as the slab is a preform).  Local bolts would be required to anchor the slab.